# How do I write an if-else statement in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I would like to convert these double if statenments into an if-else statement.

```
(if (symbol? x)
            (begin
              (display "ONE")
            )
    )
(if (integer? x)
            (begin
              (display "TWO")
            ) 
)
```

Without using racket.

Comment: I assume that "without using Racket" you mean, only using standard Scheme, right?

Comment: They are not statements, they are expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Using only standard Scheme, we have `cond` for this:

```
(cond ((symbol? x) (display "ONE"))
      ((integer? x) (display "TWO"))
      (else (display "OTHER")))
```

If you have some sort of restriction and you *must* use `if`, we can nest it:

```
(if (symbol? x)
    (display "ONE")
    (if (integer? x)
        (display "TWO")
        (display "OTHER")))
```

We can remove the `begin` expressions. In the `cond` version they’re completely unnecessary, and in the nested`if` version they’re not required when there’s a single expression inside.

In both versions I added an `else` condition because some Scheme flavors make it mandatory and anyway is a best practice.